# Ecllipes giving issue with java code at the time of connecting to the database

Tags: testing

testing oracle-character-set-1 against 
    PASSED LOSSY
testing oracle-character-set-1 against 
    PASSED LOSSY
testing oracle-character-set-1 against 
    PASSED LOSSY
testing oracle-character-set-1 against 
    PASSED LOSSY
testing oracle-character-set-31 against 
    PASSED LOSSY
testing oracle-character-set-31 against 
    PASSED LOSSY
testing oracle-character-set-31 against 
    PASSED LOSSY
testing oracle-character-set-31 against 
    PASSED LOSSY
testing oracle-character-set-870 against 
    PASSED 
testing oracle-character-set-870 against 
    PASSED 
testing oracle-character-set-870 against 
    PASSED 
testing oracle-character-set-870 against 
    PASSED 
testing oracle-character-set-871 against 
    PASSED 
testing oracle-character-set-871 against 
    PASSED 
testing oracle-character-set-871 against 
    PASSED 
testing oracle-character-set-871 against 
    PASSED

Comment: i am running simple spring application which i already tested successfully but this time eclipse giving some errors msg

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please review [writing the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question) 
to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.